# How to spawn a new terminal and run some command on that using a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I want to run a set of commands out of which some I want to run simultaneously in another terminal using shelll script. Let's say I have the below four commands

```
command1
command2
command3
command4
```

First I want to start `command1` in terminal 1 & while it keeps executing (it polls data from a server for a certain amount of time) I want `command2` to start executing in terminal 2.Then when `comamnd1` finishes I want `command3` to start in terminal 1 & similarly when `command2` finishes `command4` should start in terminal 2. I need two terminals as I need to monitor output of both set of commands. How to achieve this using shell scripting ? Is it also possible to find a solution independent of terminal program, so that any one can take the script and run on their machine?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: It may just be simpler to start all the commands in the same shell/same master process, but write their output to different files and `tail -f` each output file in a different terminal

Comment: @SimonFraser as of now I am doing this work around only. But I want to know if there is any solution available for it using any language.

Comment: Actually starting more graphical terminals seems more complex and prone to failure, but if you'd like to do it then instead of just running `command2` (or similar), run the terminal app - `xterm -e command2` (if you're using xterm, if not then it depends which terminal app you have, which is where the complexity comes in)

Comment: Using `screen` might be a possible solution, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364505/bash-cron-flock-screen/36366663#36366663

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: For anyone new coming to this, you could just use tmux, see this as an example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553463/how-can-i-programmatically-get-this-layout-in-tmux

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative idea that only uses one terminal window, but prefixes all the output lines with the command name so you can easily see where they come from:

```
# start command1 in background
command1 &
# start command2, prefixing all output with its name
command2 | sed 's/^/COMMAND2: /'
# wait till finished
wait

command3 &
command4 | sed 's/^/COMMAND4: /'
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write two shell scripts that do the respective tasks in order for the respective terminals. Then if you want to use python you can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to call each command independently. This method will not wait for the processes to finish and you can tell it to run them in the shell.

For example:

```
result1 = subprocess.Popen('command1and3.sh', shell=True)
result2 = subprocess.Popen('command2and4.sh', shell=True)
```

Comment: its not opening two terminals. Both script runs simultaneously in single terminal, messing up the outputs from both the scripts.

Comment: Yea gotta agree with @oshaiken I find printing to the terminal to be a questionable method for tracking. If you need a logger initiate a logger, if you want error reporting write it to a file. But printing to the terminal feels wrong. It's not permanent and prone to user error.

Comment: as of now I read the output from files only. But I just wanted to know if there exists any universal approach to spawn a new terminal and run few commands on that independent of terminal application.

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe your requirement, there is a dependency of `command3` to `command1`, and `command4` to `command2`, but these otherwise form two sets of commands that do not interact.

One simple way to handle that is to have two separate scripts, manually open two terminals (with the terminal emulator of your choice), and launch these two scripts separately, one in each window, which would simply look like this :

**script1**

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
command3
```

**script2**

```
#!/bin/bash
command2
command4
```

The other very easy thing to do is to launch everything in a single script, but have the two sets execute separately, sending their output to different log files (which will avoid mixing them in the same terminal, but will also hide them).  It would look like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
{ command1 ; command3 ; } >/path/to/log1 2>&1 &
{ command2 ; command4 ; } >/path/to/log2 2>&1 &
```

I guess this is not what you want, however.  You probably want two terminal windows in your GUI.  Unfortunately, there is no universal way of achieving that, since we do not know what your OS and terminal program is.  This would not be possible if the terminal does not execute on the same machine as the script (unless you use GNU `screen` or another terminal multiplexing utility, first creating a terminal and after that connecting to it from another machine).

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with python, you can give a look at Python pexpect module (https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Maybe it is too much for what you want to do, but as you mentioned that you want to monitor the output of both terminals, pexpect might suit you very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
xterm -e 'echo "This echo command print in new terminal (window 1)"'
xterm -e 'echo "This echo command print in new terminal (window 2)"'
xterm -e 'echo "This echo command print in new terminal (window 3)"'
```

will start an Xterm window and tell it to execute that command.

Replace **xterm** with the actual terminal program you're using (e.g. **gnome-terminal**). It may also use different syntax for providing a command to execute, so check its documentation for the correct syntax.