# Can a process request a running shell process to run some command and receives the standard output of the command?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

In terms of Linux API, we can use `exec*` functions or `system` functions to   start running a shell which is then to run some command.

Is it possible that a process requests **an already running shell process** (e.g. a bash process) to run a command and then receives the standard output of the command? For example, commands that I would like to run in a running shell process are those which generate shell-specific state information, e.g. `dirs` and `jobs`.

Can the above be done in C, and in bash using some utilities (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435115/can-we-write-a-script-to-run-some-command-within-each-interactive-bash-shell-pro) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416632/log-background-jobs-started-in-all-the-manually-started-shells))?

For example I would like to have a C program or shell script which can get the output of running `dirs` and `jobs` in an existing shell process.

Thanks.

Comment: Not without that shell being configured for the purpose ahead-of-time.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be specific about how to configure the shell?

Comment: Depends on the details. For instance, you could run a command in the shell to read a command from a FIFO and write a result to another FIFO. If you want it to do that on command, you could trigger that code with a signal handler.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give some code examples?

Comment: Might be relevant: [Write command in one terminal, see result on other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496914/write-command-in-one-terminal-see-result-on-other-one), or [How to send output from one terminal to another without making any new pipe or file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261531/how-to-send-output-from-one-terminal-to-another-without-making-any-new-pipe-or-f.)

Comment: Not without knowing the details of your use case enough to know if those samples will actually be helpful to you, no -- we're not talking a trivial 1-or-2-line snippet, so I'd rather not take the time until I'm sure it'll meet your needs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added a link to my previous post for my use case in bash. i am also interested in coming up a user case in C.

Comment: Given that post as context -- no, that's not feasible.

Comment: @Charles: Why is that post not possible, while the post here (which I delibrately simplified) is?

Comment: ...clarifying that it's not just "a running shell process", but an *interactive* shell process you want to mess with puts a bunch of implied constraints in place. If you tried to own the meaning of, say, SIGUSR1 for every interactive shell on your system (or even your own user account), that's not likely to go well -- there are more people writing scripts than just you, and there's only a limited number of user-defined signals to hang traps off of. Moreover, an interactive shell is often waiting for a command to exit, and deferring trap execution

Comment: ...so your program trying to wait for all these interactive shells to return response data would frequently need to wait for indefinite periods.

Comment: So, what are you **actually** trying to do? If the inspection you want to accomplish needs to just look at, say, shell environment variables, current working directory, etc., then you can get a good chunk of that through procfs (with some caveats, as `/proc/pid/environ` isn't maintained as new variables are exported and unset).

Comment: @Charles: I would like to have a C program or a shell script which can get the outputs of `jobs` and `dirs` of a running shell process.

Comment: ...eh. Suppose I could write up the trap-based approach, even as fault-prone as it is. Answer incoming.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Couldn't `screen` be used for such things? Just curious, as [I've done something along these lines before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364505/bash-cron-flock-screen/36366663#36366663), although I'm confused by what the OP is asking really.

Comment: @l'L'l, ...as I read it, what you're doing in that other answer is quite different from what I understand the OP to be asking for here. Here, they're introspecting other interactive shells, which has very little to do with running a scheduled task, inside a screen session or otherwise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Ah I see, thanks. I know they are running scheduled jobs in the other question, although excluding that I know `screen` can do some nice things with especially with running multiple sessions, and processes between them — but didn't know if that would apply here, cheers!

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y Problem. Why does it have to be an existing shell? All the shells are similar if you set the environment correctly.

Comment: @Tim, ...waitaminute, you're doing this to be able to figure out what jobs got lost after a power loss? Frankly, it wouldn't be the tool I'd reach to for that purpose -- personally, I'd use a filtered-down, automatically-rotated [sysdig](https://sysdig.com/opensource/sysdig/) trace. That way you aren't dependent on shell integration / functionality, you can see processes that are/were running even without a shell, inspect specific timelines (ie. write a query asking *when* a process started it, who started it, etc); and can get to other metadata (ie. asking which processes read file X).

Comment: @Tim, ...and yes, a sysdig trace *does* give you directory history so long as you set the filter to include the `chdir` syscall.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, the other two posts were asked for taking a "snapshot" record of opened files and running jobs automatically and periodically, in case that my Ubuntu freezes for some unknown reason, so that after I reboot to recover from freezing, I can know what I was working on earlier.

Comment: *nod*. I'd argue that sysdig is a much better tool for that job, actually being *designed* to maintain a record of full-system state (as well as a trace of what happens while that record is being maintained, with configurable levels of detail depending on your sensitivity to storage use / write churn) with minimal performance overhead (compared to almost anything else capable of the same level of logging).

Comment: Also, that'll get you a record that includes `nohup`ped commands, grandchild processes, and other details that the `jobs` listing won't have.

Comment: Thank you! @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 2):

If you evaluate the following during shell startup:

```
dump_shell_data() {
  mkdir -p -- "$HOME/.shell-state" || return
  jobs >"$HOME/.shell-state/$$.jobs" 2>&1
  dirs >"$HOME/.shell-state/$$.dirs" 2>&1
}
trap dump_shell_data SIGUSR1
```

...then sending a `SIGUSR1` to shells which have run the above code will instruct those shells to jump `jobs` and `dirs` output to files named after the PID.

**Note that there are substantial caveats.** The user of a shell may run a 3rd-party script that redefines this trap; and a shell which is blocking waiting for a command to exit will not execute the trap until after that command has in fact completed.

Comment: Thanks. How would you find out all interactive shells on the system and send a SIGUSR1 to them?

Comment: `pgrep`? Or `pkill -SIGUSR1`?

Comment: Can  `pgrep` tell whether a bash process is  interactive or not?

Comment: That said, if you have all your shells running that initialization code, you could have the same initialization code schedule a periodic SIGALARM. For some very ugly implementations, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156131/can-i-trap-a-clock-signal-in-my-bash-script -- that way you don't send signals to shells that haven't been set up to handle them correctly.

Comment: That said, to answer your prior question -- if its name is `-bash` or it's passed the argument `-l`, it's a login shell; if it's invoked with `bash -i`, it's interactive. Mostly. RTFM for the full rules.

Comment: What does `-` mean in "if its name is `-bash`"? By RTFM, do you suggest reading [The bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) or something else?